# Using OR in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I am having issues using the or operator in XSLT. I need to test if a variable does not equal 00 or 09.

The current value being entered into the XSLT for Timecodehour is 09. I am using the test below to confirm that the value must be 00 or 09.

```
<xsl:template match="/">

<xsl:if test="$TimecodeHour!='00' or $TimecodeHour!='09'">
    <xsl:message terminate="yes">Timecode is not supported</xsl:message>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

The test completes correctly if I removed "$TimecodeHour!='00' or" but submitted message Timecode is not supported when I add it back in again. Could someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `and` not `or` here. `or` will be true if either of the conditions are true.

So, for example, if `$TimecodeHour` equals `09` then the expression `$TimecodeHour!='00'` returns true, and so the result of the `or` expression is true.

Using `and` will only return true if both conditions are true.

```
<xsl:if test="$TimecodeHour!='00' and $TimecodeHour!='09'">
```

Comment: You could also (in XSLT 2.0 and later) write `test="not($TimecodeHour = ('00', '09'))"`